# Encore.setOutputPath() cannot be called yet because the runtime environment doesn't appear to be configured

Tags: reactjs, webpack, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm setting webpack.config.js but I miss that warning PhpStorm message by the `setOutputPath()` function

I have the version 2018.3.2 of PhpStorm, and I am working in Linux Debian

```js
let Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .enableReactPreset()
    .configureBabel(function (babelConfig) {
        babelConfig.presets.push('@babel/preset-flow');
        babelConfig.plugins.push("@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties");
        babelConfig.plugins.push('styled-jsx/babel');
    });

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPStorm doesn't currently support webpack-encore.

Please see https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/236#issuecomment-438620314 and other comments in https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/236 for possible workarounds.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/faq.html#how-do-i-integrate-my-encore-configuration-with-my-ide

Answer (score 11):

> It fails because the Encore Runtime Environment is only configured
>   when you are running it (e.g. when executing `yarn encore dev`). Fix
>   this issue calling to `Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()` and
>   `Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment()` methods:

[source](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/frontend/encore/faq.html#how-do-i-integrate-my-encore-configuration-with-my-ide)

```
// webpack.config.js
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore')

if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

// ... the rest of the Encore configuration
```